# Adding a fieldset to an unmanaged package

Tags: package, fieldsets

Can we add a fieldset to an unmanaged package? When I tried it didn't show up for selection.
Is there anybody who faced the same situation?

Comment: Is it possible that you field set was already added as a result of a code dependency?

Comment: Could be but then it should be visible in production org. But it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are doing something wrong. Fieldsets can be easily added in packages. Please check the below screen for details[image: Fieldsets in package]